# My program runs very slow whenever RR method is called?

Tags: java, freeze

This program schedules 5 processes using FCFS, SJF, and RR with q = 1, the problem starts whenever RR method is called. NetBeans is showing that it is running but nothing is shown on output console, only FCFS and SJF Avg. waiting time and Avg. turnaround time. However, sometimes it works. I don't know what is wrong with this program.

```
package hw5;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This program schedules 5 processes using FCFS, SJF, and RR with q = 1
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class HW5 {

    // sort is a method that sorts arrivalTime array for FCFS algorithm
    public static void sort(int[] bt, int[] at) {        
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
                if (at[i] > at[j]) {                    
                    int tempAr = at[i];
                    at[i] = at[j];
                    at[j] = tempAr;                    
                    int tempBr = bt[i];
                    bt[i] = bt[j];
                    bt[j] = tempBr;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    // print the current set of processes with their corresponding burst time and arrival time
    public static void print(int[] bt, int[] at) {
        System.out.println("Process" + "\t" + "Burst time" + "  Arrival time");
        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            System.out.println("P" + (index + 1) + "\t  " + bt[index] + "\t       " + at[index]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // FCFS method that schedules processes using first come first serve algorithm
    public static int[] FCFC(int[] bt, int[] at) {
        int[] total = new int[2]; // Array to store total waiting time and total turnaround time 
        int waitTime[] = new int[5]; // Array to store wait time for each process
        waitTime[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            waitTime[i] = bt[i - 1] + waitTime[i - 1];
        }
        int turnaroundTime[] = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            turnaroundTime[i] = bt[i] + waitTime[i];
        }
        // To Calculate waitTime and turnaroundTime for each process and their total  
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            waitTime[i] = waitTime[i] - at[i];
            turnaroundTime[i] = turnaroundTime[i] - at[i];
            total[0] += waitTime[i];
            total[1] += turnaroundTime[i];
        }
        return total;
    }

    // SJF method that schedules processes using shortest job first algorithm
    public static int[] SJF(int[] bt, int[] at) {
        int[] total = new int[2]; // Array to store total waiting time and total turnaround time
        int waitTime[] = new int[5]; // Array to store wait time for each process
        int[] copyBT = new int[5];
        int turnaroundTime[] = new int[5];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            copyBT[i] = bt[i];
            sum += bt[i];
        }
        for (int t = 1; t <= sum; t++) {
            int min = 20, index = 0;
            // This for loop used to find the min. burst time each 1 time unit
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (at[j] < t && bt[j] < min && bt[j] > 0) {
                    min = bt[j];
                    index = j;
                }
            }
            bt[index]--;
            if (bt[index] == 0) {
                turnaroundTime[index] = t - at[index];
                waitTime[index] = turnaroundTime[index] - copyBT[index];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            total[0] += waitTime[i];
            total[1] += turnaroundTime[i];
        }
        return total;
    }
    // RR method that schedules processes using round robin algorithm
    public static int[] RR(int[] bt, int[] at) {
        int tq = 1; // a time slice of 1 quantum
        int[] total = new int[2]; // Array to store total waiting time and total turnaround time
        int waitTime[] = new int[5]; // Array to store wait time for each process
        int[] copyBT = new int[5];
        int turnaroundTime[] = new int[5];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bt.length; i++) {
            copyBT[i] = bt[i];
            sum += bt[i];
        }
        int t = 0; //time
        while (t < sum) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (bt[j] > 0 && at[j] <= t) {
                    if (bt[j] > tq) {
                        bt[j] -= tq;
                        t += tq;
                    } else {
                        t += bt[j];
                        bt[j] = 0;
                        turnaroundTime[j] = t - at[j];
                        waitTime[j] = turnaroundTime[j] - copyBT[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            total[0] += waitTime[i];
            total[1] += turnaroundTime[i];
        }
        return total;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] burstTime = new int[5]; // Array of burst times

            int[] arrivalTime = new int[5]; // Array of arrival times

            int[] copyBurstTime = new int[5]; // A copy array of burstTime array

            int[] copyArrivalTime = new int[5]; // A copy array of arrivalTime array

            Random r = new Random();    // r is a variable of type Random

            int[] total; //= new int[2]; // saves two values, one total wait time and second total average time 

            long startTime, estimatedTime;

            double throughput;

            // Filling the above arrays with random integer values
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                burstTime[index] = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
                copyBurstTime[index] = burstTime[index];
                arrivalTime[index] = r.nextInt(10);
                copyArrivalTime[index] = arrivalTime[index];
            }

            print(burstTime, arrivalTime); // print a set of 5 processes

            sort(copyBurstTime, copyArrivalTime); // sort copyArrivalTime in ascending order and

            // FCFS scheduling block  
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            total = FCFC(copyBurstTime, copyArrivalTime);
            estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            throughput = 5.0 / estimatedTime;
            System.out.println("FCFS\t" + "Average Waiting Time: " + (total[0] / 5.0) + "\tAverage Turnaround Time: " + (total[1] / 5.0) + "\tThroughput: " + throughput);

            System.arraycopy(burstTime, 0, copyBurstTime, 0, 5);

            // SJF scheduling block 
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            total = SJF(burstTime, arrivalTime);
            estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            throughput = 5.0 / estimatedTime;
            System.out.println("SJF\t" + "Average Waiting Time: " + (total[0] / 5.0) + "\tAverage Turnaround Time: " + (total[1] / 5.0) + "\tThroughput: " + throughput);

            // RR scheduling block
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            total = RR(copyBurstTime, arrivalTime);
            estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            throughput = 5.0 / estimatedTime;
            System.out.println("RR\t" + "Average Waiting Time: " + (total[0] / 5.0) + "\tAverage Turnaround Time: " + (total[1] / 5.0) + "\tThroughput: " + throughput);
        //}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your round-robin simulation, your clock doesn't advance if all `bt[j] > 0 && at[j] <= t`. As the arrays are seeded with random values this condition occurs randomly, so sometimes the simulation can't complete.